# How to split JSON, so key and it's value are in different row?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dropdown table, that looks like this:

logs.component:

```
<table class="table w-100">
    <app-log-line *ngFor="let json of jsonList" [json]="json"></app-log-line>
</table>
```

log-line.component:

```
<tr class="d-flex w-100 clickable"
  (click)="json == selectedLog ? selectedLog = null : selectedLog = json">
  <td class="d-flex">
    <div class="flex-column">
      <i class="material-icons pr-3" *ngIf="selectedLog == json" aria-hidden="true">
        keyboard_arrow_down
      </i>
      <i class="material-icons pr-3" *ngIf="selectedLog != json" aria-hidden="true">
        keyboard_arrow_right
      </i>
    </div>
  <td>
  <td>
  {{json.timestamp}}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{json.message | json}}
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="d-flex w-100" *ngIf="selectedLog == json">
  <td>
  </td>
  <td><pre>{{json | json}}</pre></td>
</tr>
```

aaaand
I get this JSON file from graylog server:

```
getLogList() {
    const url = `....`;
    this.http.get(url, {headers: this.getHeaders(), responseType: "text"})
      .pipe(map((res) => {
        this.csv = res;
        const CSVToJSON = require("csvtojson");
        csv().fromString(this.csv).then((jsonObj) => {
          console.log(jsonObj);
          this.json = jsonObj;
        });
        return res;
      })).toPromise().then(body => console.log(body))
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('There was an error!', error);
      });
  }
```

I want to display the json like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNBZ0.png
I tried to split the JSON file by ":", but wasn't successful.
Can you share any other idea? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get keys according to your requirement so in the square bracket `[0]` means it passing index you can check out more info [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#:%7E:text=JavaScript%20arrays%20are%20zero%2Dindexed,invalid%20index%20number%20returns%20undefined%20.)

## Just Example

---

```js
var array = [
  { source: 'xyz' },
  { stream: 'abc' },
  { timestamp: '2020-12-12 06:25:25' },
];

console.log(`
  source : ${this.array[0].source},
  stream : ${this.array[1].stream},
  timestamp : ${this.array[2].timestamp}
`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` to get keys of json object and `Object.values` to get values of json object